# Pig load a map using PigStorage(',')

Tags: csv, dictionary, apache-pig

I have been trying to load a data (CSV) like:

txt = IPHONE,GA,US,CN,[bucket#A,type#user,jailbreak#No],app_talkingtom,ios7

using Apache Pig load statement:

```
raw = LOAD text USING PigStorage(',') as (phone:chararray,loc:chararray,country:chaarray,ctype:chararray,kyval:map[],appname:chararray,osver:chararray);

gen = foreach raw generate appname;

DUMP gen;
```

I get

**type#user** instead of **app_talkingtom**;

I know its a delimiter (',') issue. I cant change the delimiter as the file is huge. 
How do I make Pig load that map properly?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your load:

```
raw = LOAD text USING PigStorage(',') as (phone:chararray,loc:chararray,country:chaarray,ctype:chararray,kyval:map[chararray],appname:chararray,osver:chararray);
```

make sure all the values are chararrays in the map.

Answer (score 0):

PigStorage is counting the commas inside your map (`[bucket#A,type#user,jailbreak#No]`) as delimiters.

That is why your field values are off from your field names.

> PigStorage is an extremely simple loader that does not handle special cases such as embedded delimiters or escaped control characters; it will split on every instance of the delimiter regardless of context. For this reason, when loading a CSV file it is recommended to use [CSVExcelStorage](http://help.mortardata.com/integrations/amazon_s3/csv) rather than PigStorage with a comma delimiter.

(Source: http://help.mortardata.com/technologies/pig/pigstorage)

Comment: With above script I get  (IPHONE,GA,US,CN,,type#user,jailbreak#No]), with 
 CSVExcelStorage() not recognizing [ as map. Do I miss some thing here